# How to monitor HTTP requests on Android?

Tags: android, http, monitoring

I want to record device-wide (if possible, otherwise monitoring only for my app will suffice) HTTP requests **programmatically** from within my Android app.
Software like [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) are not suitable because that would require my phone to be connected to my laptop while I monitor the traffic.

I want to capture HTTP traffic without the need of a computer or some web service. I do not have a rooted phone, so non-rooted options are preferred.

I had a go at using the [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#retrieveNetworkLogs(android.content.ComponentName,%20long)), but the documentation is terrible and incomplete... so I was not able to get it working.

Any ideas?